# EPSG:27700 missing from available CRS in GeoServer

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

What would cause EPSG:27700 to not be available as a CRS in an out-of-the-box installation of GeoServer?

I've been using GeoServer on Windows for years with no issues, but as an experiment our IT services team have installed a GeoServer install into Kubernetes.

On this install I'm only seeing a very short list of available CRS.

Any obvious thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: The most likely issue is the user running tomcat not having write permission to the temp directory where GeoServer unpacks the epsg data. You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.